# Center image vertically and to the right in a div

Tags: html, css

I would like to center the image with ID "image" to right and vertically.

With PHP I create my DIVs as follow:

```
echo 
    "<div class=\"first\">
    <div id=\"second\"><label id=\"second_div_label\"></label>
    <img id=\"image\" src=\"images/my_image.png\"/>
    </div>
    <div id=\"third\"></div>
    </div>";
```

My CSS code is

```
.first {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#second {
    margin-top: 5%;
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px;
}

#third {
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
}   

#image {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    float: right;
}
```

Thanks to `float:right` the image is to the right of DIV but it isn't vertically center and `margin-bottom` doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `position:absolute` trick then set it to the right and vertically center using Sebastian Ekström's [wonderful code](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).
Please note that for this to work, the parent tag must have `position:relative`

Since the element is absolutely positioned, there is no need for `float:right`

Example:

```css
.first {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#second {
    margin-top: 5%;
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 20px;
    position:relative;
}

#third {
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
}   

#image {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right:10px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
    <div id="second">
      <label id="second_div_label"></label>
      <img id="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE5lz.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

P.S you might want to add vendor prefixes for the transform property

```
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS by Aziz should work in modern browsers.
However, for an effortless cross-browser experience, and if you don't mind using javascript, you might consider using jQuery like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#image').position({
            my: 'right center',
            at: 'right center',
            of: '.first'    //or whichever container you wish to use
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then you wouldn't need to implement the floating and the relative and absolute positioning in CSS.

Comment: That's an interesting solution tho it creates a javascript dependency and won't work for people who have javascript disabled

Answer (score 0):

```
#image {
        width:35px;
        height:35px;
        float:right;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
```

Pls add this style to image. And note that one more thing, you have to define a height to the parent div(id=second) and its value is larger than image height.